# How to direct router traffic to my PC?

Tags: router, gateway, network-traffic

I have a router and 4-5 devices connected to it over WiFi. Now I want all the traffic that is generated from every connected device to pass through my PC, where I can perform some task like filtering, **authorization** etc. This is how i feel the packet flow should be,

multiple devices --> router --> PC (where processing happens) --> internet

or

multiple devices --> router --> PC (where processing happens) --> router --> internet

I tried to find a solution but could not find anything precise. I think my PC has to act as a gateway, but all this is little confusing. My final goal is my PC should be able to authorize whether a device can connect to internet or not.

Answer (score 0):

No Way, you have to put some hardware in between, like an Access Point or an Hardware-Firewall.
EDIT: there's a way, you could use your PC as an Access-Point.

Comment: can u please guide me a little more with some explanation how Access Points or other hardware can help me achieve what i want here ?